# Why can I load all data from an object, but not individual values?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to understand what is going on here.
I am using axios to get data from my database into my vue application.
The data appears when I inspect the page

[image]

I am able to display ALL the data on the page by using the following code.

```
<template>
   <div v-for="property in propertyInfo">
    <p>{{ property }}</p>
   </div>
</template>

export default {
data: () => ({
  propertyInfo: [],
methods: {
  getInfo(){
    axios.get(`bi/stats/property/company`, {timeout: 300000})
        .then(response => this.propertyInfo = response.data)
        .catch(error => this.propertyInfo = error.data);
  },
},
created() {
  this.getInfo()
},
 }
```

But I only want to display specific data. For example I only want to display currentNumberEmptyUnits, but when I try to call for that specifically I get an error messages.

What I tried:

```
  <div v-for="property in propertyInfo">
    <p>{{ property.currentNumberEmptyUnits }}</p>
  </div>
```

**ERROR:** "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'currentNumberEmptyUnits')"

```
  <div v-for="property in propertyInfo">
    <p>{{ property.bIGraphStats.currentNumberEmptyUnits }}</p>
  </div>
```

**ERROR:** "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'currentNumberEmptyUnits')"

I don't understand why I am getting this error. propertyInfo is an array, not null, and currentNumberEmptyUnits is not null either, and if run the code without trying to ask for a specific value, then it can show all the data just fine.
How do I get it to show only that specific value without getting the error message?

Comment: "propertyInfo is an array" - the image shows that it's an object, not array. The error means that `property` is null.

Comment: Is `response.data` an array or an object?

Comment: response.data is an object as shown in the image. The object called bIGraphStats. I am trying to extract the individual values from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you use `v-for` for `propertyInfo` and `propertyInfo` is the object `bIGraphStats`. To access property `currentNumberEmptyUnits` need change template to

```
  <div>
    <p>{{ propertyInfo.currentNumberEmptyUnits }}</p>
   </div>
```

`v-for` - need use for arrays